# Unsubscribe notification

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, rx-android, rxandroidble

With the help of a button, the user can receive notifications of a characteristic. The following code will be executed:

```
connection.setupNotification(setDescriptorEnableNotification(tmpCharacterostoc, connection))
  .flatMap(notificationObservable -> notificationObservable)
  .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .subscribe(bytes -> 
    //data processing
  );
```

If the user clicks on the button again, the notification should be unsubscribed, so that no notifications are received.

**How can i do this?**

I have tried to set the value of the Descriptor to `BluetoothGattDescriptor`. `DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The subscribe method returns a Subscription, hold its instance and when you’re no longer interested in notification just call ‘unsubscribe’ on it.

The library will disable notifications for you.